# Java, classes

Tags: java, классы

Есть метод

```
public void a(Object b) {...}
```

Параметр `b` может иметь значения `new c();` или `new d();` или `new e();` или...
В классах `c`, `d`, `e`, ... присутствует метод `cast()`, который нужно вызвать вместо "..." в функции `a`.
Я новичок в программировании, как это сделать?
(Если непонятно расписал - скажите)

Comment: Java — язык с сильной типизацией. Так, как вы описываете, не получится. В ответах есть обходные манёвры.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Классы `c`, `d` и `e` должны быть унаследованы от общего класса или, что лучше, реализовывать общий интерфейс. Тогда, немного изменив сигнатуру метода `a`, вы получите, что хотели.

```
public interface Castable {
    void cast();
}

public class c implements Castable {
    public void cast() {  ... }
}

public class d implements Castable {
    public void cast() {  ... }
}

public class e implements Castable {
    public void cast() {  ... }
}

.......

public void a(Castable b) {
   b.cast();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void a(Object b) {
   ((c)b).cast();
}
```

вызов

```
a(new c());
```

и лучше что бы `new c();` или `new d();` или `new e()` были от одного родителя

Comment: @Gorets У класса `Object` нет метода `cast()`, так что такой способ не сработает.

Comment: точно, но мне лень расписывать теорию и исправлять :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Casts {
public class A {}

public class B {}

public class C {}

public void someMethod(Object x) {
    if (x instanceof A) {
        A a = (A) x;
        // ...
    } else if (x instanceof B) {
        B b = (B) x;
        // ...
    } else if (x instanceof C) {
        C c = (C) x;
        // ...
    }
}
```

}

Но, всё же, старайтесь не делать так - instanceof довольно медленный метод сравнения.
Наследуйте все классы от абстрактного класса, а в нем создайте булевые методы isA(), isB(), isC(), которые возвращают False, и которые в реализациях перезаписываете с возвратом true.

Я бы вообще сделал так:

```
public class Casts {
public abstract class SomeBasicClass {
    public boolean isA() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isB() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isC() {
        return false;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return (A) this;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return (B) this;
    }

    public C getC() {
        return (C) this;
    }
}

public class A extends SomeBasicClass {
    @Override
    public boolean isA() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class B extends SomeBasicClass {
    @Override
    public boolean isB() {
        return true;
    }
}

public class C extends SomeBasicClass {
    @Override
    public boolean isC() {
        return true;
    }
}

public void someMethod(SomeBasicClass x) {
    if (x.isA()) {
        A a = x.getA();
        // ...
    } else if (x.isA()) {
        B b = x.getB();
        // ...
    } else if (x.isA()) {
        C c = x.getC();
        // ...
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Это убивает всю идею наследования: абстрактный класс знает всех своих потомков, клиентский класс знает всех потомков абстрактного класса.

Появится класс D и нам придется править и `Casts` и даже `SomeBasicClass`.

Comment: И вообще, чем больше в коде `if`'ов, тем он хуже. Не говоря уж об `instanceof`!

Comment: @Евгений Карпов почитайте про шаблон визитор

Comment: Адовая жесть. Ваш `someMethod` можно использовать в лекциях по `ООП` в качестве примера, как не надо писать.